# Retrieve all drivers software data in visual basic 2010

Tags: vb.net

i'm working on a system information project and i need to get all drivers data from a  computer.  I have been searching for the location of how windows retrieves the information as in device manager.

Driver Versions brand and model about the driver in a static form so that i can run this tool on both of my systems and get the information everytime.  Hope you can help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**WMI** is your friend.

Here's a simple routine that will provide you with all the information you're requesting from all the installed drivers:

```
Dim objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")

Dim colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_PnPSignedDriver")

For Each objItem In colItems
    Console.WriteLine("Manufacturer: " + objItem.Manufacturer)
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " & objItem.DeviceName)
    Console.WriteLine("Version: " & objItem.DriverVersion)
    Console.WriteLine("Signed: " & objItem.IsSigned)
    Console.WriteLine()
Next
```

For more information about the properties provided by the "Win32_PnPSignedDriver" object, please refer to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394354%28v=vs.85%29.aspx